# How to align just in the middle images?

Tags: html, css

I have set up some icons on my website but there is one (the "zoom" icon) that is not aligned. It is on the top of the container. I had to use justify content with the space-evenly option to order all the images. I have tried everything but I can not figure out.  It must be a silly question for the experts but this is my first website. I am attaching the images as evidence.

Thanks in advance

The CSS and HTML code

```css
@import url(menu.css);
@import url(slider.css);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #9acd32;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='152' height='152' viewBox='0 0 152 152'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg id='temple' fill='%23ffffff' fill-opacity='0.17'%3E%3Cpath d='M152 150v2H0v-2h28v-8H8v-20H0v-2h8V80h42v20h20v42H30v8h90v-8H80v-42h20V80h42v40h8V30h-8v40h-42V50H80V8h40V0h2v8h20v20h8V0h2v150zm-2 0v-28h-8v20h-20v8h28zM82 30v18h18V30H82zm20 18h20v20h18V30h-20V10H82v18h20v20zm0 2v18h18V50h-18zm20-22h18V10h-18v18zm-54 92v-18H50v18h18zm-20-18H28V82H10v38h20v20h38v-18H48v-20zm0-2V82H30v18h18zm-20 22H10v18h18v-18zm54 0v18h38v-20h20V82h-18v20h-20v20H82zm18-20H82v18h18v-18zm2-2h18V82h-18v18zm20 40v-18h18v18h-18zM30 0h-2v8H8v20H0v2h8v40h42V50h20V8H30V0zm20 48h18V30H50v18zm18-20H48v20H28v20H10V30h20V10h38v18zM30 50h18v18H30V50zm-2-40H10v18h18V10z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

header {
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.contenedor {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}

.brand {
    width: 160px;
    margin: 3px 10px;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/*QUIENES SOMOS*/

#quienes_somos {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*NUESTROS PROFESIONALES*/

#profesionales {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    
}

#profesionales .contenedor {
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.doctor img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
}


/*CONSULTAS Y CITAS*/

#consultas {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}


#consultas .images {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;    
    
}


/*FOOTER*/

footer .contenedor {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: small;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 250px;
}

@media (min-width:1024px) {
    
    .contenedor {
        width: 1000px;
    }

    #profesionales .contenedor {
        display: flex;
    }

    .doctor {
        width: 50%;        
        
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Balance-Salud Mental</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Tu salud mental es importante, cuidala con los profesiones adecuados. "/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="brand" alt="Salud Mental Peru">
        </a>
        
            
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
        <label class="icon-menu-outline" for="menu-bar"></label>
    
        <nav class="menu">
        <a href="quienes_somos.html">¿Quienes Somos?</a>
        <a href="nuestros_profesionales.html">Nuestros Profesionales</a>
        <a href="consultas_citas.html">Consultas y Citas</a>
        <a href="blog.html">Artículos</a>
        </nav>
    </div>            
</header>

<main>
<section id=consultas>  
    <h2>Consultas y Citas</h2> <br>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <p> Consultorio: Av. Arequipa 2555, Lince. Lima. <br>    
                Debido a la coyuntura actual, tambien estamos realizando las consultas a través de videollamadas en la 
                plataforma de tu preferencia.
            </p>
    

            <div class="images">
                <img src="img/whatsapp-png.png" width="70px" height="70px"/>
                <img src="img/skype-png.png" width="100px" height="70px"/>
                <img src="img/messenger-png.png" width="70" height="70px"/>
                <img src="img/meet-png.png" width="70" height="70px"/>
                <img src="img/zoom-png.png" width="120" height="40px"/> 
            </div>
       
            <p>
                Comunícate (whatsapp) y agenda tu cita:
            </p>

            <p>
                Psiquiatría: (+51)999888777 <br>
                Psicología: (+51)999888777
            </p>
        </div>
</section>
</main>


<footer>
    <div class="contenedor">
    <p>2018-2020 Balance Salud Mental &copy; - Designed by Watermelon</p>
    </div>
</footer>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any images. You'll need to include the absolute paths to run the code here or link to a working version elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I also cannot see the images, but I think I have a pretty good guess about what's happening there. Try adding `align-items: center` to your `#consultas .images` ruleset and that should fix it.

The reason why they do not look aligned vertically is that you set a different height for your zoom image from your other images. `justify-content` only aligns them horizontally, to align the items vertically within a flex container, you can use `align-items`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's gotta do something with the height of the image. Try increasing the height of the zoom image to maintain with others.

Try this line with height of 70px

```
<img src="img/zoom-png.png" width="120" height="70" />
```